# How to dump json of last 30 minutes updates of django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to dump json of last 30 minutes updates in a model/table.

I used the code bellow, but its not giving me desired result.

Its always giving me the last/recent(1 object) update instead of 30 minutes data.

the code I used:

```
def encode_complex(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Verification):
            mydict = dict()
            mydict['id'] = obj.id
            mydict['asset_code'] = obj.asset_code
            mydict['scan_time'] =obj.scan_time.strftime('%b.%d,%Y, %I:%M %P')
            mydict['credential'] = obj.credential
            mydict['status'] = STATUS_CHOICES[obj.status]
            mydict['operator'] = obj.operator
            mydict['location'] = obj.location
            mydict['auth_code'] = obj.auth_code
            mydict['emp_id'] = obj.emp_id

            return mydict

    #This gives updates of last 30 minutes in json dump

    def get_latest_verification(request):
        data = Verification.objects.filter(scan_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800))
        arraydata = []
        map(lambda x: arraydata.append(x), data)
        encodeStr = json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).encode(arraydata)
        return HttpResponse(encodeStr)
```

can any one correct me...

Comment: What is intended by `map(lambda x: arraydata.append(x), data)`? That does the same thing as `arraydata = data[:]`. Which is the same thing as just using `data`, since you're not touching it again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`serialization`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) in django. So your function can be updated to

```
def get_latest_verification(request):
        from django.core import serializers
        data = Verification.objects.filter(scan_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800))
        encodeStr =  serializers.serialize("json", data)
        return HttpResponse(encodeStr)
```

No need for `encode_complex()` function.